# ImportError: cannot import name 'OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR'

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have been trying to install django-oscar but it gives me this error when I try to make migrations (via : `python manage.py migrate`).

> ImportError: cannot import name 'OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR' from 'oscar'
>   (C:\Users\dell\Envs\eshop\lib\site-packages\oscar__init__.py)

#### Code I am using:

```
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/0bf3b0a5393b06c3cc99ba8f82373c6ecb0bf21a/docs/source/releases/v2.0.rst#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-oscar-20) for 2.0+ (2019-07-04):

> `OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR` setting has been removed and existing templates updated with the full path. See [issue:`1378`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1378), [issue:`2250`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2250). Please update your templates accordingly.